# yankstack newer yank not cycling

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am using yankstack (last from [github](https://github.com/maxbrunsfeld/vim-yankstack)) on gvim7.3 on windows, I have these mappings

```
let g:yankstack_map_keys = 0
nmap <A-p> <Plug>yankstack_substitute_older_paste
nmap <A-[> <Plug>yankstack_substitute_newer_paste
```

works fine, iterates over older yanks, but  always inserts previous one, and if  again, inserts again the previous one, without overwriting the former.

Comment: You should try to [create an new issue](https://github.com/maxbrunsfeld/vim-yankstack/issues?page=1&state=open).

Comment: will do, if this turns out is a bug and not some misconfiguration on my side

Comment: Try `nnoremap` instead of `nmap`, then.

Comment: nnoremap does not help, A-[ does nothing in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are calling `yankstack#setup()`in your .vimrc before defining your mappings.

Test it without `let g:yankstack_map_keys = 0`, using the default keys `alt-p`
and `alt-shift-p`, so you will be able to tell if the problem is related to
your mappings.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but my problem was that I was using `nnoremap` instead of `nmap`.